# Categories assigned to user model - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Within my rails app I have two models. A User model and a Book model. A user uploads and has many books.

I'm trying to add 10 predefined categories to the user model, so that a user assigns as many of the 10 categories to themselves as they wish. For example, if i'm a user that uploads a several books, and the categories I chose in my user settings are "fiction" and "science"

If another user chooses "fiction", "science", "history" as their categories, I want to be able to show them all books uploaded by users that are under these three categories including all the books I uploaded since I am under the categories of "fiction" and "science"

**What is the best way to implement this?** I was thinking of using the [acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) but maybe this is too heavy weight and necessary. Should I just add a string column to my user model where each category is separated by a comma, so that I can split them up into an array and do queries with Active Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you could create your own solution for the problem but [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) is a very good solution for it. It is not such a heavy weight as other gems.

Bonus: You can go back any time if it becomes too heavy for your application. Which I doubt.

Comment: Thank you!! If I use this gem, how would I write a query to show all books where the users that uploaded them have common categories to the current_user ?

Comment: Please create a new question with an example dataset and the code of your models.